# Can new drummers be downloaded into Logic Pro?

Tags: plug-ins, plugins, drum, logic

I was wondering if there are other drummers that can be downloaded or created by users.
Interested in Latin rhythms like bossa, samba, huapango, etc.
maybe even a 3rd party plug in or something